# How to get information from foreign key owner table?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, oracle10g

I have a  table named Employee with columns:

- employee_name
- Street
- City`.

Also have another table named 'works' with columns:

- employee_name,
- company_name
- salary`

Here `employee_name` in `works` is a foreign key of the column `employee_name` in `Employee` table.

Now how do I find the street and city of 'Employee' table on a specific company_name?

The query will be something like:

```
select street, city from Employee where company_name (in works table) ='XYZ';
```

I'm working on Oracle 10g database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner join

```
select 
   Employee.employee_name
    , Employee.street
    , Employee.city 
    from Employee 
    INNER JOIN works on Employee.employee_name = works-employee_name
    where works.company_name ='xyz'
```

Comment: Getting Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined, Probably i make those table in a weired way, trying to figure out the solution.